# "ERROR","timestamp":","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool]Failed to connect to seed broker,trying another broker from the list:Failed to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I am trying to connect to the AWS MSK cluster. Now when I am trying to create topics or any operations to the MSK cluster from my EC2, I am getting a timeout error.

```
"Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)"
```

. I have referred internet and whitelisted all traffic for every port in every IP, in inbound, and as well as outbound rules for my development purpose. The EC2 and AWS MSK are in the same VPC.

Comment: I suggest contacting MSK support since they'll have more information about connection limitations. Otherwise, you need to share what code you're running and what configs